# IntelliSense Option Greyed out on SOME Servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, intellisense

I just installed SQL Management Studio 17.2 and I am experiencing some issues with IntelliSense. It's not that IntelliSense doesn't work at all, but only on "some" servers.

[image: IntelliSense Greyed out]

I've tried everything I came across in other threads, such as refreshing IntelliSense local cache, Enable/Disable from Tools > Options > Text Editor > IntelliSense, increased maximum script size for IntelliSense to 5 MB, Checked / Unchecked "Auto list members" and "Parameter information" under Transact-SQL > General, but with no result. The option is still greyed out on two of the servers. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its to do with the version of the SQL server you are connecting to.  It must be at least sqlServer 2008 (v10) for IntelliSense to work.

Answer (score 1):

Most Microsoft IntelliSense options are on by default. You can turn off an IntelliSense option and instead invoke it through a menu command or keystroke combination.

here is a link explain how to Configure IntelliSense-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/configure-intellisense-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: in that link there is another link "how to troubleshoot IntelliSense" can you try it?

Comment: Tried that as well... It's not like IntelliSense is not working at all... The problem is it's only working on certain Servers... Still, I can't find any info regarding SSMS 17.2 IntelliSense's compatibility with older SQL Server versions such as 2005 or 2008...